# How to generalize Firestore Object behavior in Swift to avoid repetition?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am writing an iOS app in Swift, using Firestore as a database. I have classes representing my Firestore objects that look like this:

```
class FirestoreObject: Decodable, Hashable, ObservableObject {
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case attributeA = "attribute_a"
        case attributeB = "attribute_b"
    }
    
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    @Published var attributeA: Double
    @Published var attributeB: String
    
    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        _id = try container.decode(DocumentID<String>.self, forKey: .id)
        self.attributeA = try container.decode(Double.self, forKey: .attributeA)
        self.attributeB = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .attributeB)
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }
    
    static func == (lhs: FirestoreObject, rhs: FirestoreObject) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    
}
```

This pattern is the same for all of my Firestore objects. How can I generalize this to avoid repeating myself? The hash and the == functions can always be exactly the same, and the init(from decoder:) will always work exactly the same, although of course the keys/attributes differ from object to object.

I looked into protocols and inheritance, but I'm still new to Swift and I'm not sure the right way to go about it. The main thing is trying to automatically provide the default init that works the way I want to -- it's pretty much the same as the default init(from: decoder) that swift provides for Decodable.

Comment: make the `class` a `struct` and use the default implementations of `Hashable`, `Codable` and `Equatable`. having equatable and hashable only consider `id` is a setup for a lot of bugs. SwiftUI relies on those heavily

Comment: @loremipsum Sorry, I should have made this more explicit, but I want the objects to be `ObservableObject`s, which is why it's a `class` and not a `struct`. Is there a way to have a `struct` conform to `ObservableObject`?

Comment: No there isn’t, two different approaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best solution here is to add a super class that all your Firestore types inherits from

```
class SuperFirestoreObject: ObservableObject, Decodable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case id }
    
    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        _id = try container.decode(DocumentID.self, forKey: .id)
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }
    
    static func == (lhs: SuperFirestoreObject, rhs: SuperFirestoreObject) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}
```

Then you will need to add a `init(from:)` in all the subclasses to decode the specific attributes for that sub class

```
class FirestoreObject: SuperFirestoreObject {
    @Published var attributeA: Double
    @Published var attributeB: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case attributeA = "attribute_a"
        case attributeB = "attribute_b"
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.attributeA = try container.decode(Double.self, forKey: .attributeA)
        self.attributeB = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .attributeB)
        try super.init(from: decoder)
    }
}
```

I don't think you can generalise it much more than that unless you could use struct and wrap them in a generic class that conforms to ObservableObject but then only the object would be published and not the individual properties.

Something like

```
class FirestoreObjectHolder<FirestoreObject>: ObservableObject where FirestoreObject: Hashable, FirestoreObject: Decodable {
    @Published var object: FirestoreObject

    init(object: FirestoreObject) {
        self.object = object
    }
}
```

Then the actual type would be quite easy to implement

```
struct FirestoreObjectAsStruct: Hashable, Decodable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    let attributeA: Double
    let attributeB: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case attributeA = "attribute_a"
        case attributeB = "attribute_b"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. I mostly wanted to know how much generalization was possible, e.g. if there were some tricks that I wasn't aware of. I like the second approach, too. I'll have to figure out which one works best. Thanks again :)

Comment: Firebaser here. I would not recommend this approach - you want your data model be all structs, and the view model to be a class that is an ObervableObject. See our documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/swift-codable-data-mapping

Comment: Well I am not a Firebase so I simply tried to answer the question in a general swift way.

Answer (score 1):

Firestore supports Swift's `Codable` protocol, which makes mapping a lot easier: For most cases, you won't have to write any mapping code. Only if you have special requirements (e.g. mapping only some document attributes, or mapping attributes to property with a slightly different name), you will have to add a few lines of code to tell Codable which fields to map, or which properties to map to.

Our documentation has a comprehensive guide that explains the basics of `Codable`, and some of the more advanced use cases: [Map Cloud Firestore data with Swift Codable  |  Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/swift-codable-data-mapping)

In a SwiftUI app, you will want your data model to be structs, and only the view model should be a `class` conforming to `ObservableObject`.

Here is an example:

### Data model

```swift
struct ProgrammingLanguage: Identifiable, Codable {
  @DocumentID var id: String?
  var name: String
  var year: Date
  var reasonWhyILoveThis: String = ""
}
```

### View Model

```swift
class ProgrammingLanguagesViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var programmingLanguages = [ProgrammingLanguage]()
  @Published var newLanguage = ProgrammingLanguage.empty
  @Published var errorMessage: String?
  
  private var db = Firestore.firestore()
  private var listenerRegistration: ListenerRegistration?
  
  fileprivate  func unsubscribe() {
    if listenerRegistration != nil {
      listenerRegistration?.remove()
      listenerRegistration = nil
    }
  }
  
  fileprivate func subscribe() {
    if listenerRegistration == nil {
      listenerRegistration = db.collection("programming-languages")
        .addSnapshotListener { [weak self] (querySnapshot, error) in
          guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
            self?.errorMessage = "No documents in 'programming-languages' collection"
            return
          }
          
          self?.programmingLanguages = documents.compactMap { queryDocumentSnapshot in
            let result = Result { try queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: ProgrammingLanguage.self) }
            
            switch result {
            case .success(let programmingLanguage):
              // A ProgrammingLanguage value was successfully initialized from the DocumentSnapshot.
              self?.errorMessage = nil
              return programmingLanguage
            case .failure(let error):
              self?.errorMessage = "Error decoding document: \(error.localizedDescription)"
              return nil
            }
          }
        }
    }
  }
  
  fileprivate func addLanguage() {
    let collectionRef = db.collection("programming-languages")
    do {
      let newDocReference = try collectionRef.addDocument(from: newLanguage)
      print("ProgrammingLanguage stored with new document reference: \(newDocReference)")
    }
    catch {
      print(error)
    }
  }
}
```